# Test Explorer Discovery Fails Unless Run As Administrator in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am running Visual Studio 2017 & the Test Runner cannot discover the Unit Tests unless Visual Studio is running as an Administrator.  Running as Administrator is next to impossible at my new workplace.

As such...

**Q:** How can get the Test Explorer to discover Unit Tests without being an administrator?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I have confirmed the following...

- POSITIVE: The Unit Test Project is set to build
- POSITIVE: The Test Project is a genuine Unit Test Project (w/ magic guids)
- NEGATIVE: The Test View is not an available option in VS2017 Community Edition

[image]

Comment: You should not need to be an admin for this. Are you using the latest updates for VS2017? Are you using Resharper? If so, ensure you're using the latest updates for that too.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the folder/directory *Visual Studio* is writing to re: unit tests? I'm pretty sure the IDE writes to a `TestResults` folder, and it *might* cache data in `%appdata%`.  Just a thought.  *Visual Studio's* log file might give you some insight.  See: [Debugging a Visual Studio Crash](http://blog.masterdevs.com/debugging-a-visual-studio-crash/)

Comment: @Matthew Watson Yes,VS2017 is updated (well...no new ones are showing).  They do not use ReSharper here & forbid it.

Answer (score 3):

A summary of various fixes for this **no tests found** issue.

---

You have 2 versions of the Microsoft.TestAdapter installed (reference `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions`). Check NuGet Package Manager, version 1.1.11 doesn't work, you need to use 1.1.18 (at time of writing for it to work).

Also check your Bin folder &/or your Build Agents references folder for duplicate versions.

---

Make sure that your test project is set to build. If the test assembly isn't being built, VS won't be able to find any tests:
[image]

---

Magic GUIDs are needed in the Test Project:

**C#:**

```
{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
```

**VB:**

```
{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}
```

[image]

---

Trying to get ignored tests running again. Same error message occurs if you remove the Ignore label. Does not automatically re-enable the test. This article takes you through the last step. http://richallen.blogspot.com/2008/05/ms-test-re-enabling-ignored-tests.html

Ie

> Open the Test List Editor, selected the ignored test, right click and select "Enable" from the context menu.

[image]

---

Make sure your method belongs to a class with the `[TestClass]` Attribute and the method it's marked with the  `[TestMethod]` Attribute.

---

- Use Test View to find your test.
  [image: Test View]
- Open your Properties window (<kbd>F4</kbd>), and make sure your test is enabled
  [image: Enabled]

---

Some people have accidentially added a Class Library project instead of Test Project. Running Tests in a Class Library doesn't work, it has to be a Test Project, *probably because of the Magic GUIDs*.

---

Check whether the solution is running on 64bit. If so change it to x86.

---

Marking tests as static makes them fail to appear in the test list.

---

Close down Visual Studio and delete the .vsmdi (visual studio test meta data) file. This will be regenerated.

Comment: I dont get the same properties list off the UNIT TEST PROJECT that you do...how are you getting that list? (I am using VS2017)

Comment: Hi, I'm using vs2017 Ent. Edition. Can you please give me more information. Did you confirm all the above? And it's only the properties of the project that differ? You do have a unit test project yeah, not a class library?

Comment: I updated the question - only the Text Expolorer window option is available

Comment: That's ok, you wouldn't have disabled them then. Can you please do 3 things 1) post the contents of your Output Window when you try to run the Tests, 2) post the Test class code, 3) run a [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) traces and quickly reproduce the problem with both admin and non-admin. Save both traces as CSVs and compare them using your fav DiffMerge tool and [edit] your question with noteworthy info.